# Dates transformation using CLEM expression(spss modeler)

Tags: date, spss, spss-modeler

i hope, that here there is specialist of clementine or IBM SPSS MODELER.
My question: How use Clem expression to transform date?
For example i have this format of date

```
27.10.15.15:05
27.10.15.15:45
27.10.15.16:10
```

if the date value < 30 then, round to 1 min
i.e. not 15:05, but 15:01 , if the date value > 30 min then, round to 31 min, i.e. not 15:45, but 15:31. What about 16:10, since it  < 16:30 then, round to 16:01.
generally speaking date must be in the follow format

```
27.10.15.15:01
27.10.15.15:31
27.10.15.16:01
```

One man  told me, that it's should to use this expression `datetime_in_seconds(?)`
But i really don't know how use it. Please help me to transform this date in needed for me format

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. Maybe anyone needs in this desicion.
Modeler has uncomfortable possibilities for data transformation

```
if (abs(time_mins_difference(datetime_time(time), datetime_time(datetime_hour(time), 1, 0))) < 15) then
datetime_timestamp(datetime_year(time), datetime_month(time), datetime_day(time), datetime_hour(time), 1, datetime_second(time))
else if (abs(time_mins_difference(datetime_time(time), datetime_time(datetime_hour(time), 1, 0))) > 15) and (abs(time_mins_difference(datetime_time(time), datetime_time(datetime_hour(time), 1, 0))) < 45) then 
datetime_timestamp(datetime_year(time), datetime_month(time), datetime_day(time), datetime_hour(time), 31, datetime_second(time))
else
datetime_timestamp(datetime_year(time), datetime_month(time), datetime_day(time), datetime_hour(time)+1, 1, datetime_second(time))
endif
endif
```